# WinRT: In there any way to (Json,XML) serialize a XAML UIElement in C#?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to save the properties of a XAML UIElement (Grid, Button, TextBlock..etc.) and restore it again, by saving the whole control..
So my first option was to JSONize -serialize- the control and save it as string then restore it by JsonConvert method in Newtonsoft.Json:

Here's my code:

```
Grid grid = new Grid { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) };
string jsonStringGrid = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grid);
```

But, an weird exception says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Then i tried to make a class with the properties i want, so no need to serialize a whole grid, just my new class:

```
 public class MyGridClass
        {
            public Brush Background { get; set; }
            public Thickness Margin { get; set; }
        }
```

No complicated types and properties.. but the same exception is happening again.

Then I tried to change the `Brush` type to a `string` with just "Red" to test it, and I tried to serialize it and it's working!!

Whats the problem with the Brush type?
Is there anyway to save a XAML control and restore it w/o manually serialization ?

I don't know what exactly the properties that I can't parse or serialize, but if there's a list of these properties, that'll be good for me..

Comment: One guess is that the `Dispatcher` property of `Brush` is causing the/a problem. It definitely wasn't intended to be serialized.

Comment: Might make sense to mark one of the answer as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is painfully simple. The XAML `Brush` is not serializable.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, Do you know any way to do what i want? Regardless the serialization ..

Comment: Well, assuming the brush is a SolidColorBrush with 100% opacity you can extract the Color from it, and use only that to serialize. That being said, the Brush can also be a LinearBrush or a WebBrush with varying opacity which makes extracting and rehydrating it very complex.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Windows.UI.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.aspx) is serializable. Just keep that as the property. Then use

```
var newBrush = new SolidColorBrush(newColor);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes for the UI.Color, but no for the Brush, which is my case :)